# Sorting multiple subarrays based on a total count from all sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have some data which looks like this (reduced)

```
Array
(
    [datasets] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => NEW
                    [backgroundColor] => #37fdfd
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 0
                            [2] => 5
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Grade A
                    [backgroundColor] => #76ef76
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8
                            [1] => 12
                            [2] => 11
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Grade B
                    [backgroundColor] => #f9f96d
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 6
                            [2] => 5
                            [3] => 3
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Grade C
                    [backgroundColor] => #f3ca36
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                            [1] => 0
                            [2] => 1
                            [3] => 4
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Grade D
                    [backgroundColor] => #f3ca36
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 3
                            [1] => 0
                            [2] => 1
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [labels] => Array
        (
            [0] => User 0
            [1] => User 1
            [2] => User 2
            [3] => User 3
        )

)
```

Here is a JSON string of the data (not reduced, numbers may differ slightly)

```
{"datasets":[{"label":"NEW","backgroundColor":"#37fdfd","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"label":"Grade A","backgroundColor":"#76ef76","data":[9,14,12,0,4,17,13,0,10,0,18,18,12,13,13,4]},{"label":"Grade B","backgroundColor":"#f9f96d","data":[1,6,5,0,6,5,2,0,1,0,2,1,4,3,1,15]},{"label":"Grade C","backgroundColor":"#f3ca36","data":[3,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]},{"label":"Grade C","backgroundColor":"#f3ca36","data":[3,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]}],"labels":["User 0","User 1","User 2","User 3","User 4","User 5","User 6","User 7","User 8","User 9","User 10","User 11","User 12","User 13","User 14","User 15"]}
```

Each `dataset` has an array of `data` which has keys that directly relates to a key in the `labels` array. This is currently sorted in alphabetical order by the label.

This data structure is the structure required for Chart.js, which I am using to display a stacked bar chart on my webpage.

Essentially what I need to accomplish is to sort the `data` array for every user in the `labels` array based on the sum of each data set for that user. I also need to sort the `labels` array to be in the same order.

My original idea on how to achieve this is to create a temporary array, loop through all the data sets and add them to this temporary array in the order necessary, but I got stuck after calculating the total for each user. Here is my attempt:

```
$return = [];

foreach($calculated['labels'] as $key => &$name) {

    $total = 0;

    foreach($calculated['datasets'] as $dataset) {

        $total += $dataset['data'][$key];

    }

    echo "$name - $total<br>";

}
```

How can I sort my data and labels in descending order based on the total for each user from all datasets.

Here is my expected output for the reduced data above

```
Array
(
    [datasets] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => NEW
                    [backgroundColor] => #37fdfd
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => 5
                            [1] => 0
                            [0] => 0
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Grade A
                    [backgroundColor] => #76ef76
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => 11
                            [1] => 12
                            [0] => 8
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Grade B
                    [backgroundColor] => #f9f96d
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => 5
                            [1] => 6
                            [0] => 1
                            [3] => 3
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Grade C
                    [backgroundColor] => #f3ca36
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => 1
                            [1] => 0
                            [0] => 3
                            [3] => 4
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Grade D
                    [backgroundColor] => #f3ca36
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [2] => 1
                            [1] => 0
                            [0] => 3
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [labels] => Array
        (
            [2] => User 2 //23 total across all data sets
            [1] => User 1 //18 total across all data sets
            [0] => User 0 //15 total across all data sets
            [3] => User 3 //7 total across all data sets
        )

)
```

The `key` in the `labels` array acts as a unique identifier for each user in each `dataset` `data` array.

Notice how each set of `data` inside of each `dataset` is in the same order, as is the `labels` array. Each set should be ordered by the total amount from all sets for each user, not necessarily the highest number in each dataset.

For clarification, each set of `data` in each `dataset` contains a list of values, the key for each value is directly related to the key for each user in the `labels` array. So in my example, we have User 0 who has the `key` "0". This user has a total of 23 from adding up the values from each `dataset` with the key "0".

Comment: just to clarify - are you wanting to order the data array or the total sum of the data arrays?

Comment: It would be better to reduce your data and provide __expected results__.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton haha OK will rm my comments :)

Comment: @treyBake Added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete solution:

```
// get array
$a = json_decode('{"datasets":[{"label":"NEW","backgroundColor":"#37fdfd","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"label":"Grade A","backgroundColor":"#76ef76","data":[9,14,12,0,4,17,13,0,10,0,18,18,12,13,13,4]},{"label":"Grade B","backgroundColor":"#f9f96d","data":[1,6,5,0,6,5,2,0,1,0,2,1,4,3,1,15]},{"label":"Grade C","backgroundColor":"#f3ca36","data":[3,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]},{"label":"Grade C","backgroundColor":"#f3ca36","data":[3,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]}],"labels":["User 0","User 1","User 2","User 3","User 4","User 5","User 6","User 7","User 8","User 9","User 10","User 11","User 12","User 13","User 14","User 15"]}', true);

// get array of arrays with `data` key from each data set
$users = array_column($a['datasets'], 'data');

// tricky code to sum arrays
$sums = array_map('array_sum', array_map(null, ...$users));
// sort array with keeping keys
arsort($sums);

// we need flip so as `array_replace` will work as expected
$keys = array_flip(array_keys($sums));

// "sorting" `data` subarrays
foreach ($a['datasets'] as &$item) {
    $item['data'] = array_replace($keys, $item['data']);
}
// "sorting" `labels` subarray
$a['labels'] = array_replace($keys, $a['labels']);
// see the result
print_r($a);
```

Fiddle here https://3v4l.org/a7rPL

Answer (score 1):

I see this task as a perfect candidate for `array_multisort()`.  Your synchronously sorted subarrays don't need to retain their initial keys like in u_mulder's output.

The first parameter must be the array of columnar sums, then the descending sort flag as the second parameter, then the labels subarray as a reference, then the dynamic number of data subarrays as references to the original array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7IACW))

```
$params = [[], SORT_DESC, &$array['labels']];
foreach ($array['datasets'] as ['data' => &$data]) {
    foreach ($data as $i => $d) {
        $params[0][$i] = ($params[0][$i] ?? 0) + $d;
    }
    $params[] = &$data;
}
array_multisort(...$params);
var_export($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a typical job for map(reduce).sort: map each element to an *object* with `id`, so you can preserve "which user this used to be" information, and `total`, the result of reducing `data`. Then sort with a custom sort function `(a,b) => a.total - b.total`.

E.g.

```
function map_total($user, $pos) {
  return array(
    "id" => $pos,
    "total" => array_sum($user.data)
  );
}

function cmp_total($a, $b) {
  return $a["total"] - $b["total"];
}

$mapped = array_map("map_total", $thing.dataset, array_keys($thing.dataset));
$sorted = usort($mapped, "cmp_total");
```